# Выход за пределы массива при закрытии приложения

Tags: lazarus

У меня вот такой обработчик OnChange, который позволяет вводить в Edit только определенные символы (кириллица, латиница, без пробелов, т. е. одно слово).

```
procedure TForm1.Edit2Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  symbols, textInEdit: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  symbols := 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъьыэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЬЫЭЮЯ';
  textInEdit := Edit2.Text;

  for i := UTF8Length(textInEdit) downto 1 do  // Берем строку с новыми символами
  begin
    if (UTF8Pos(UTF8Copy(textInEdit, i, 1), symbols) = 0) then  // Если хотя бы один символ отсутствует в наборе символов...
    begin
      Edit2.Text := textBefore;  // записываем в Edit прежнюю строку
      Edit2.SelStart := curPos + selLen;  // и устанавливаем курсор в прежнюю позицию
      Break;
    end
    else
      Edit2.SelStart := curPos + (UTF8Length(textInEdit) - UTF8Length(textBefore) + selLen);  // Устанавливаем курсор при вставке (с выделением или без)
  end;

  textBefore := Edit2.Text;  // Строка до входа в обработчик
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  curPos := Edit2.SelStart;  // Определение позиции курсора
  selLen := Edit2.SelLength;  // Длина выделения
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2Enter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  curPos := Edit2.SelStart;  // Определение позиции курсора
  selLen := Edit2.SelLength;  // Длина выделения
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  curPos := Edit2.SelStart;  // Определение позиции курсора
  selLen := Edit2.SelLength;  // Длина выделения
end;
```

Всё работает вроде бы хорошо, но в некоторых случаях при закрытии приложения выскакивает ошибка: "Проект ... вызвал класс исключения 'External: SIGSEGV' по адресу 40F298", т. е. выход за пределы массива. Меня интересует - почему эта ошибка возникает именно при закрытии приложения?
Пример:
Ввожу слово mice, выделяю букву i, нажимаю пробел (запрещённый символ), i, как положено, остаётся на месте, но при закрытии приложения вылетает ошибка.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если не пытаться ввести недопустимые символы, то ошибки при закрытии не возникает?

Comment: range check включен в опциях компилятора?

Comment: Да, если недопустимые символы не вводить, то ошибки при закрытии не возникает.